# Why when i change manualy the url on my react page it ignores the .css file?

Tags: css, reactjs, url

When i manually change the url **http://localhost:3000/overview/all** to for example **http://localhost:3000/overview/al** it shows the page but with 0 css like it ignores the file completely,
in my index.html I import it like this in the

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all">`

the index.htm is in the public folder

and it works fine in any case and in any view,
I don't know if it is important but in my App.js the Router is writen like this

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
    <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="overview" element={<Overview />}>
         <Route path=":category" element={<Overview />} />  
    </Route>  
    <Route path="details" element={<Details />} />
          
</Routes>
```

One thing i tried is to manually change the url to **http://localhost:3000/overview** and it works perfectly so it happens when I include **/something** at the end,

when I call it to navigate to the page from another component like this

```
const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    navigate(`/overview/${searchValue}`, { replace: true  } );
  };
```

it works perfectly with the css and the url is as it should be ,
like this **http://localhost:3000/overview/searchValue**
where **searchValue** is what the user put in the search field and called the **onSubmit**

What i noticed is that there is no **?** as i know from my experience in url parameters but it didn't seem to be a problem in the functionality of the page and the page can read them properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS file is loaded with a relative (to the current path) path:

```
 href="css/style.css"
```

which, when appending another PATH to the url ( like `/overview/something/css/style.css`), renders the css path wrong..

if `css/style.css` is in your ROOT web folder` you need to use:

```
 href="/css/style.css"
```

this way `/css/style.css` will be consistently loaded from the web root `/`

Comment: Thank you very much it worked , i didn't know the "/" played that important role , i always thought it wasn't necessary.

Comment: Yep, it tells the browser "from where" to start loading the included file